# Designing monthly postpaid invoice module

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

We currently have an invoice system that generates a monthly invoice by reading all the transactions in the  database of a certain user for that month at the billing point of the month.

The invoice module and the transaction module lives in the same monolith and database.

Problem is this process is very expensive and takes a bit of time specially if that user have lots of transactions(millions) for that month.

We were wondering if there is a design pattern /architectural approach for this problem?

We are open to extracting out the invoice module potentially to it's own service, but just trying to figure out how to implement it properly.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's your goal?  Speeding up the final invoice process because it's taking too long?  Spreading out the load so that performance doesn't suffer?  Is this an on-demand process?

Comment: @RobConklin It's to speed up the process. Currently, it takes too long to generate one for people who have big transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this can be predictably rolled up on a daily basis, just run a batch process every night to roll up the previous day's transactions into a summary row.  If it's still too much, run it hourly.  Just ensure you have all the records (1 per hour) before calling the invoice done.  Most invoicing systems are on batch processes, not dynamic queries for just this reason.